# Mysql select to php string

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a football site. A player can have these results: 0, 1 or 3 (loss, draw, win)

I want to see what results a certain player got in his last 3 matches. I want to add the result (should be a number combined with 3 possible results mentioned before)

This is my code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events_regged WHERE result IS NOT NULL AND registrant_name='John' ORDER BY id DESC limit 3") or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

 $form = $row['result'];
 echo $form;
 if ($form == '333') {echo 'Won 3 times in a row';}
}
```

The problem here is that I get 3 times the number 3 and not the number 333. I think I do not need a '`while`' statement here.

How can I do it?

Comment: stop using mysql_ -functions the are deprecated...

Comment: $form .= $row['result']

Comment: downvoted for using mysql_ function

Comment: `$form = '';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

 $form .= $row['result'];
}
 if ($form == '333') {echo 'Won 3 times in a row';}`

Comment: I am just a beginner trying  to code. Instead of downvoting you could help me learn this language. Eventually you could downvote and tell he how to do it in mysqli

Comment: @user1159265 starting point would be tutorials. and then go over SO answered questions already.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events_regged WHERE result IS NOT NULL AND registrant_name='John' ORDER BY id DESC limit 3") or die(mysql_error());
$maxwins = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    $form = $row['result'];
    if ($form==3)
        $maxwins++;
    else
        $maxwins = 0;
    if ($maxwins == 3) {
        echo 'Won 3 times in a row';
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your snippet.
First of all when using `=` previous value will be overwritten.
What you need to do is concat those results in order for your condition to be satisfied.

Second, you are checking for a condition in a loop.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {    
 $form .= (string) $row['result'];
}
if ($form == '333') {echo 'Won 3 times in a row';}
```

There are a number of ways of doing this, solution above requires minimal modification of your snippet.

Btw. `mysql_*` has been depreciated for a while now. Take a look at `PDO`.

Answer (score 0):

This query will return three rows:

```
SELECT *
FROM events_regged
WHERE result IS NOT NULL AND registrant_name = 'John'
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 3;
```

If you want the values in one row, then use aggregation.

Here is one method:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(result ORDER BY id DESC) as results
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM events_regged
      WHERE result IS NOT NULL AND registrant_name = 'John'
      ORDER BY id DESC 
      LIMIT 3
     ) e
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you e4c5 for the answer.
This fixed the problem:

```
$form .= $row['result']
```

Comment: this is more better:- `$form = ''; while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) { $form .= $row['result']; } if ($form == '333') {echo 'Won 3 times in a row';}`  every time execution of  `echo $form;` and `if ($form == '333') {echo 'Won 3 times in a row';}` is not needed. put outside